# Where is my mistake in the following example about Viterbi algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, hidden-markov-models, viterbi

I am trying to learn Hidden Markov Model, Viterbi algorithm. Therefore I was looking for an example to study. I came across a simple example from this [link](http://idiom.ucsd.edu/~rlevy/lign256/winter2008/ppt/hmm_viterbi_mini_example.pdf);

Up to the position 3 I understood everything. However in position 3 when calculating A;

```
 - δ(A) = max { 0.2 x 0.6 x 0.063, 0.7 x 0.7 x 0.7 }
        = max { 0.00756(A), 0.09604(B) }
```

Since the **B** value is greater than **A** value we select **B** in state 2 for **A** in state 3. The value for **A** in state 3 should be 0.09604

To calculate **B** value in state 3;

```
 - δ(B) = max { 0.7 x 0.6 x 0.063, 0.2 x 0.7 x 0.196 }
        = max { 0.02646(A), 0.02744(B) }
```

Since the **B** value is greater than **A** value we select **B** in state 2 for **B** in state 3.  Therefore the value for **B** in state 3 should be 0.02744

However in the example for state 3 the values are calculated in the example as follows;

```
δ(B) = 0.02646

δ(A) = 0.02744
```

Different from my answers.

I am still learning the subject so it is likely that I am making a mistake. However I can't see where.

Why am I getting different answer? What is the problem in my solution?

Comment: I also got the same results as you, looks like a typo to me.

Comment: thanks for checking. That is what I think now as well.